# How can I put two contour plots into the same figure while displaying only one legend?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

`testfig = ContourPlot[Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLegends -> Automatic];`

`testfig2 =  ContourPlot[Cos[x^2 + y^2], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

This produces two plots which have the same legend - not surprising since the plotted function is bounded between $-1$ and $1$.

How can I place the two plots into the same figure and only use one legend? It's easy enough to put them on the same plot using `GraphicsGrid`, but that yields a figure with two legends.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

size = 250;

testfig = ContourPlot[Sin[x^2 + y^2],
   {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
   ImageSize -> size,
   PlotLegends -> Automatic];

testfig2 = ContourPlot[Cos[x^2 + y^2],
   {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
   ImageSize -> size];

Row[{testfig, testfig2}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For a legend below

```
testfig = ContourPlot[Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
   ImageSize -> size];

Legended[Row[{testfig, testfig2}],
 Placed[BarLegend[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", {-1, 1}}, 
   LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** For larger legend

```
Legended[Row[{testfig, testfig2}], Placed[
  BarLegend[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", {-1, 1}},
   Range[-1, 1, 0.2],
   LegendLayout -> "Row",
   LegendMarkerSize -> 500], Below]]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to position the legend centered on the bottom of the figure?

Comment: @Moo that only places it below one of the contour plots, though. Is there a way to place it below both contour plots?